# How to modify HTML code inside Python code?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm working with Django in order to create a website. I have an function which send e-mail message that is called with a button in the HTML file. 
I would like to insert a python variable to the HTML code inside of the python function:

```
import smtplib, ssl, getpass

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def mailfunctionejex(receiver_email, subject, message, passwordtest):
    port = 465
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    sender_email = 'senderg@gmail.com'
    failcounter = 0

    #MIME parameters

    mailmessage = MIMEMultipart()
    mailmessage['Subject'] = subject
    mailmessage['From'] = sender_email
    mailmessage['To'] = receiver_email
    mailmessage['Bcc'] = receiver_email

    #Message content

    html = '''\
        Good morning, the user {sender_email} has send you a message: \n

        {message} #I would to insert in {} the variable sender_email and             #message 

        '''

    #Conversions
    htmlpart = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    mailmessage.attach(htmlpart)


.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a string like any other one, so this should do (I added an f before the string to tell Python it's a format string):

```
html = f'''\
        Good morning, the user {sender_email} has send you a message: \n

        {message}  

        '''
```

If this doesn't work, you can go the old way:

```
html = 'Good morning, the user'+ sender_email+ 'has send you a message: \n'

        +message
```

Comment: If f-strings aren't an option, I'd suggest using `str.format` before going for `str` concatenation, e.g. `'Good morning, the user {} has send you a message:\n{}'.format(sender_email, message)` or the f-string-like `'Good morning, the user {sender_email} has send you a message:\n{message}'.format_map(locals())`. String concatenation involves many temporary strings (it's a Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm), requires all inputs to already be `str` (where `str.format` will stringify implicitly), and is uglier (subjective opinion).

Comment: I'm glad it did !